# Comparison of 2 same backbone models (i.e) 2 different instances of a backbone model

Tags: backbone.js

Is there any way to compare the 2 difference instances of a same backbone model?

Comment: You want to test whether two instances have the same attributes or whether your two references point to the same object? For the former `_.isEqual(m1.attributes, m2.attributes)` or, if you want to limit the compared attributes, `_.isEqual(m1.pick("attr1", "attr2"), m2.pick("attr1", "attr2"))`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare? Everything? attributes? Prototype? It's not clear what you want.

Comment: I don't want to compare the attribute's value manually by passing the attribute's name. Instead when i give the models it should know by itself that this is the attribute and this is the value and then compare the values to know it equal or not

Answer (score 2):

You commented:

> I don't want to compare the attribute's value manually by passing the attribute's name. Instead when i give the models it should know by itself that this is the attribute and this is the value and then compare the values to know it equal or not

There's no built in method that compares the model to another model. But you can implement a method on the `Backbone.Model` prototype to do this:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.equalTo = function(other) {
    return _.isEqual(this.attributes, other.attributes);
};
```

It utilizes [Underscore's `isEqual()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual) which compares whether two objects are equal. `isEqual()` get's passed both [internal Backbone data objects `attributes`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-attributes).

You can then do:

```
if (m1.equalTo(m2)) {
    console.log("equal");
}
```

If you don't want to modify `Backbone.Model`, you can extend from it and implement `equalTo()` there.